Jenkins deprecated plugins not allowing to uninstall?
I have installed Jenkins (not in any container), and installed few plugins. It is showing a few of them are deprecated, but not allowing me to uninstall them, as the buttons are disabled.
How do I uninstall the plugins? Because even after restarting, it is not resolving the issue.


You will first need to uninstall or disable any other plugins that depend on the deprecated one.
Simply move your mouse over the grayed-out buttons, and Jenkins will display what plugins you need to uninstall.

Always double-check you won't need the plugin before removing it. Being deprecated doesn't necessarily mean it is unsafe to use.
